# Config Haproxy front-end to redirect client requests from Host/A/* to Host/B/* when request equals Host/A/*

Tags: url-rewriting, haproxy, http-status-code-301

I run a web server (RHEL7) that uses haproxy v1.5 as the front-end for remote client requests and host a farm of web-applications each running in specific directories off the web-doc root (i.e. /App001/*, /App002/*, etc..).

I recently renamed one of the application folders and reconfigured the app to use the new location and it works fine, but we have old documentation that points to the old app subfolder and I'd like haproxy to redirect the remote client requests seeking the old location (i.e. /OldAppFolder/*) to the new location (/NewAppFolder/*) to avoid a page-not-found error.

The redirect must be conditional such that it only redirects client requests seeking /OldAppFolder/*

Is this easy? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will rewrite the URL transparently to the user.

```
reqrep  ^([^\ :]*)\ /OldAppFolder/(.*) \1\ /NewAppFolder/\2 if { path_beg /OldAppFolder/ }
```